# Oncoming, outcoming and forward meaning

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context

What are the meaning of the following three words in a context? (I know the meaning by themselves but I can't quite picture what they mean)

- **Oncoming** lane
- **Forward** lane
- **Outcoming** lane

I am not really sure but the third one might be a typo.

Can someone illustrate me on the meaning of these?

Comment: So what is the context? Are we talking road signs?

Comment: The only one of the three I've heard used is the first. An "oncoming lane" is one carrying traffic coming towards you.  "Forward lane" sounds intriguing. It seems to imply that there might also be a "backward lane"! "Outcoming lane" sounds as though it might be either an exit lane or a joining lane.

Comment: The context appears to be road use. You might find the [UK Highway Code useful](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code) in this case.

Comment: @KateBunting automobile driving.

Comment: From the examples given by Collins, it appears that _oncoming lane_ may mean either 'the lane in which the traffic is heading towards you' or 'the road ahead'! I couldn't find definitions for either of the other two, so the third may indeed be a typo.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard the word "outcoming", whether applied to a lane or not. I also suppose that it's a typo (perhaps a mish-mash of "outcome" and "outgoing").

Comment: I can't find *any* colocations for "outcoming lane" in any corpus.   I don't think it's actually used, so you'll have to infer from context what your writers actually meant - and possibly notify them that their meaning is unclear!   On the other hand, "outcoming" itself has been in common use for most of the post-industrial-revolution era (1850-present).   Its use is overwhelmingly but not exclusively in descriptions of machinery, and it to exclusively modify the /moving/ part of a system, so "outcoming lane" seem to imply the lane is leaving the road!

Answer (score 1):

Did you make up these phrases? The only one that really makes sense is the first one, "oncoming lane."

The **oncoming lane** is the lane that has traffic coming toward you. On a two-lane road, you might have to move into the oncoming lane to pass a slow car that's in front of you.

I suppose a forward lane could be any lane that's in front of another lane, but I don't believe it's a commonly used term.

There is an **outgoing** lane of traffic that carries people away from a certain place, but I've never heard of an "outcoming lane."

Comment: Obviously I did not. It is part of the code and documentation of software written by non native speakers, and I am trying to make sense of it.

Comment: I've never heard of "outcoming" lane either, but it seem entirely possible that this refers to the merging land of an entry ramp. From the point of view of people on a freeway or interstate, people entering are "coming out of" an entrance ramp.